# restricting access only through domains on nginx on virtual hosts

Tags: nginx

I have finished setting up nginx for virtual hosting, this is how my config files look like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    access_log /home/domain.com/prod_webapp/logs/access.domain.com.log;
error_log /home/domain.com/prod_webapp/logs/error.domain.com.log;
    location /static {
            root /home/domain.com/prod_webapp/mocorner/ph/;
    }
location / {
    try_files $uri @uwsgi;
}
location @uwsgi {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/domain_uwsgi.sock; 
}}
```

on the same machine, I have domain1.com and domain2.com, each when i access I get its content which is great. My problem is that when i try to access the user using the IP address i get one of the sites in the virtual hosts too..

Although i disabled the default (removed the symbolic link) from sites-enabled folder but still not solved it for me.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may handle such requests by creating the default webserver configuration like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

This option is called `default_server` since 0.8.21. See [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Just insert a [catch all block](http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample#A_Default_.22Catch_All.22_Server_Block) and restrict access to every other request to your IP.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```